# How to serialize/deserialize third party Java objects with Jackson

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, jackson

As an example, I'd like to serialize/deserialize one object of Slick2d's [Animation class](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/Animation.html) using Jackson. What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Why was my question edited to have Americanised spelling?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can annotate a mix-in interface if you want to control the generated json on third party classes.

read more here: [http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations](https://web.archive.org/web/20110829212918/http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations)

**Update**: The current documentation (v2+) is here: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations

Comment: This has worked well so far, thank you. I'll wait until I get a response from @Bozho regarding the alternative before I set the answer though, as the other way requires far less effort.

Comment: I've now encountered a problem on writing objects to JSON, where Jackson serialises _every_ field that it can. This leads to stack overflows for some classes and massive dumps of binary data in others. Is there a simpler way than `@JsonIgnore`ing every getter/field?

Comment: I think I've found the [solution](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/02/entry_443.html) to that, though I'm not sure if there's a way to disable auto-detection bar a few fields...

Answer (score 2):

Just as any object - pass it to `objectMapper.readValue(..)` / `objectMapper.writeValue(..)`

Comment: Wow, trying to write code in a comment really sucks on this site. Forget that... The Animation constructor that I'm interested in takes two arguments: an array of Image objects (which takes a String named ref in its constructor) named frames and an integer named duration. I wrote a unit test to try it out: [http://pastebin.com/9F7uZQjX](http://pastebin.com/9F7uZQjX)

Also, [here](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/javadoc/index.html?org/newdawn/slick/Image.html) is the Image documentation to show the Image constructors.

Comment: Mix-ins annotations can be used to denote constructor to use, if that helps. Sometimes custom deserializers are simplest way, for most exotic third-party types.